# How to get second largest column value and column name

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, unpivot

How can I get second largest column value and its name?

My current query gives it mostly correct but in cases where largest and second largest values are same I am getting wrong values.

```sql
    select item_code, A, B, C, 
        greatest(A, B, C) as largest1, 
        greatest(case when largest1 = A then 0 else A end,
                 case when largest1 = B then 0 else B end,
                 case when largest1 = C then 0 else C end) as largest2,
        (case largest1 when A then 'A'
                       when B then 'B'
                       when C then 'C' end) as largest1_column_name,
        (case largest2 when A then 'A'
                       when B then 'B'
                       when C then 'C' else 'None' end) as largest2_column_name 
        from table1
```

Below is the sample table:

```sql
+-----------+----+----+----+
| item_code | A  | B  | C  |
+-----------+----+----+----+
| p1        | 20 | 30 | 40 |
| p2        | 50 | 30 | 10 |
| p3        | 30 | 50 | 10 |
| p4        | 30 | 30 | 30 |
| p5        | 50 | 50 | 10 |
| p6        |  0 |  0 |  0 |
+-----------+----+----+----+
```

Below is expected output:

```sql
+-----------+----+----+----+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
| item_code | A  | B  | C  | largest1 | largest2 | largest1_column_name | largest2_column_name |
+-----------+----+----+----+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
| p1        | 20 | 30 | 40 |       40 |       30 | C                    | B                    |
| p2        | 50 | 30 | 10 |       50 |       30 | A                    | B                    |
| p3        | 30 | 50 | 10 |       50 |       30 | B                    | A                    |
| p4        | 30 | 30 | 30 |       30 |       30 | A                    | B                    |
| p5        | 50 | 50 | 10 |       50 |       50 | A                    | B                    |
| p6        |  0 |  0 |  0 |        0 |        0 | A                    | B                    |
+-----------+----+----+----+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

This is the output I am getting from my query (I have marked wrong as comment):

```sql
+-----------+----+----+----+----------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| item_code | A  | B  | C  | largest1 |  largest2   | largest1_column_name | largest2_column_name |
+-----------+----+----+----+----------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| p1        | 20 | 30 | 40 |       40 | 30          | C                    | B                    |
| p2        | 50 | 30 | 10 |       50 | 30          | A                    | B                    |
| p3        | 30 | 50 | 10 |       50 | 30          | B                    | A                    |
| p4        | 30 | 30 | 30 |       30 | 0/*wrong*/  | A                    | NULL/*wrong*/        |
| p5        | 50 | 50 | 10 |       50 | 10/*wrong*/ | A                    | C/*wrong*/           |
| p6        |  0 |  0 |  0 |        0 | 0/*wrong*/  | A                    | A/*wrong*/           |
+-----------+----+----+----+----------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Dont add images for data and output. it should be added as inline test in the question

Comment: What should happen for those wrong results ? iImean what it should display ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 I have given the expected output. In largest2 it should be second largest value even if it is equal to the largest value. Here it should be 30 for p4, but I am getting 0.

Comment: If there is a tie, does it really matter which column it choses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a slight variation of this (`listagg` instead of `string_agg`) in Snowflake and it seemed to be getting the expected result

```
with cte (item_code, abc, id) as
(select item_code, a, 'a' from table1 union all
 select item_code, b, 'b' from table1 union all
 select item_code, c, 'c' from table1)
 
select item_code, 
       max(case when id='a' then abc end) a,
       max(case when id='b' then abc end) b,
       max(case when id='c' then abc end) c,
       split_part(string_agg(abc::varchar,',' order by abc desc),',',1) largest1,
       split_part(string_agg(abc::varchar,',' order by abc desc),',',2) largest2,
       split_part(string_agg(id,',' order by abc desc),',',1) largest1_col,
       split_part(string_agg(id,',' order by abc desc),',',2) largest2_col
from cte
group by item_code;
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes this method worked with listagg. I just changed it as below: split_part((listagg(id, ',') within group (order by abc desc)),',',1) largest1_col,

Answer (score 0):

This might be simpler achieved by unpivoting the rows, ranking the values, and then using conditional aggregation. In Postgres, you could phrase this as:

```
select t.*, x.*
from table1 t1
cross join lateral (
    select 
        min(val) filter(where rn = 1) largest1,
        min(val) filter(where rn = 2) largest2,
        min(col) filter(where rn = 1) largest1_column_name,
        min(col) filter(where rn = 2) largest2_column_name
    from (
        select x.*, dense_rank() over(order by val desc) rn
        from (values ('a', a), ('b', b), ('c', c)) as x(col, val)
    ) x
) x
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this, but I am getting error  (Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "select" ). This error is coming at the select min(val) position. Just to confirm does this method work on redshift? I am on redshift. I tagged postgre as usually postgre method works in redshift.